# How do I disable completion for a specific command in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I want to disable completion for the `make` command, so when I type `make <tab>`, zsh doesn't try to parse Makefile. It should be done temporarily (e.g. for this zsh session only, so removing files is not the solution).

I have a Makefile of 228k lines and zsh freezes when I try to `make` something there. I've tried `unfunction _make` and `compdef -d make`. They don't work.

I'm using nothing fancy, just `compinit` that comes with zsh.

Comment: In a quick test, `compdef -d make` appeared to work for me, with `make` targets no longer appearing in the completion list. Running `compinit` brought them back.  Maybe you'll have better luck changing the completion function instead of deleting it, e.g. with `compdef _files make`.

Comment: Yes, `compdef _files make` works for me. `compdef -d make` also seems to work now. Maybe I did something wrong in a hurry yesterday.

Comment: Rather than `_files` the default for commands without a completion is `_default`. `compdef -d` should work. If not, `unset _comps[make]` is a way to force things.